# Google Sign-in - Detect if already logged in and prompt user

Tags: google-signin

Spotted this pop-up modal in the wild while visiting the TripAdvisor website. The fact that I was currently logged in to Google, was detected, and this prompt appeared as a sign-up prompt.

Can anyone tell me more about this? I haven't seen anything like this described in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#add_a_google_sign-in_button).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the new [One-tap sign-up and auto sign-in on websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/)
 feature from Google Identity, which was announced at [Google IO '18](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGGMgEfSzMw)

But for now, beta program is closed. We should wait for new public beta program or GA release.

Comment: Thanks. Wish there was a way to sign up for news on that.